# What the fastest way in java to receive absolute value of double?

Tags: java, absolute

I use code like:

```
Double getabsValue(final Object[] value){

if (value==null) return null;
if (value.lengt==0) return null;

final Double absValue=Maths.abs(value[0]);

if (absValue>0) return absValue
else return null;
```

But in my application I have problem with performance.
How it can be optimized?

Maybe better use?

```
if (absValue>0) return absValue
else return absValue<0?-absValue:null;
```

Thanks

Comment: How sure are you that `Math.abs()` is the performance bottleneck?

Comment: Does this code compile? It should not as `java.math.Math#abs(...)` does not allow for an `Object` as parameter.

Comment: it does not get any quicker than your latest edit i.e. `if (absValue>0) return absValue
else return -1*absValue;`

Comment: @Shahzeb: Actually, it might... using `>= 0` will avoid the `Double.valueOf` call in the case of 0, and *may* also be a faster comparison (as it only needs to check a single bit, I suspect). I don't know whether there's a cached value for `Double.valueOf(0)`, but if there isn't, the boxing could make a significant difference if the value is frequently 0.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for bringing that up it is people like you that make SO what it is today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the code you've got at the moment won't even compile - there's no `Math.abs(Object)` call as far as I'm aware. However, assuming you *actually* have a cast to `Double` there, you're going to be boxing all the time. You could avoid boxing when the value is already greater than 0, and avoid the call when the value *is* 0, like this:

```
static Double getAbsValue(Object[] values) {
    if (values == null || values.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    Double value = (Double) values[0];
    return value > 0 ? value
         : value == 0 ? null
         : -value;
}
```

By the time we get to the final option, we already know that the value is negative, so we don't really need the call to `abs` any more.

It's not really clear what the context is here. You say you've got a performance problem, but is it *definitely* in this code?

EDIT: Your latest code shows:

```
if (absValue>0) return absValue
else return -1*absValue;
```

That doesn't do the same thing - it doesn't return null if the array contains a boxed 0 value, as your original code does.

**You should focus on correctness before performance.**

What do you want your code to do with an input of 0? If you want it to return 0, then I would use:

```
return value >= 0 ? value : -value;
```

If you want it to return null, use the code I provided originally.

Why include a multiplication by -1 rather than just use the unary negation operator, by the way? I would expect either the compiler or the JIT to get rid of that anyway, but fundamentally you don't *want* to be performing multiplication - you want to perform negation. Make your code read as closely as possible to how you'd describe your aims.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about casting to (Double)

Comment: @user710818: If you're casting to `Double`, then chances are that the autoboxing and auto-unboxing going on in this method (and *probably* all over your code) has a **much** greater effect on your performance than any calls to `Math.abs()`. Profile it and see for yourself.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer that is certainly true but is there a way around it though for OP .

Comment: @Shahzeb: if he *insists* on changing *only* the posted code, then he won't get far. He'd *probably* need to do some bigger modifications. Still: he **must** profile it **before** changing anything.

Comment: +1: correctness is more important than performance. It doesn't matter how fast you can do something which is not correct 99.9% of the time. I would point out that using `double` is faster than using `Double` or `Object` but I suspect here its doesn't matter,

Answer (score 3):

> I use code like:

```
Double getabsValue(final Object[] value){
```

Why?

The first thing I would do with this is redefine the signature.

- It is pointless to specify `Object[]` when it basically has to be a `Double[]`, or at least an `Object[]` which *contains* Doubles, otherwise it will throw a ClassCastException.
- Why specify an array when you only use the first element?
- Why a `Double` when what you really need is a `double`?

So I would redefine it it to take a single argument of type `double`. That moves the overhead of getting things out of the array back to the caller where he can see it. He may not even *have* an array, so he would have to construct it to call this method. And he may already have a double not a Double, in which case again he or the compiler would have to box it into a Double.

The second thing I would do with it is review what's left after this change. The change gets rid of the null and length checks, and the typecast, so all you are left with is `return Math.abs(d);` So it becomes clear that the entire method is basically pointless.

So the third thing I would do with it is delete it.